# How can I add a plugin to the registry while using a Zend_Form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception, registry, zend-form

I have a zend form that I'm initializing as follows:

$form = new Form_XYZ();

I have a display group in that form, which I'm calling like this:

```
    $form->addDisplayGroup($generalSettingsGroup,
                           'general',
                            array(
                                'legend' => 'General',
                                'disableDefaultDecorators' => true,
                                'decorators' => array(
                                                    'FormElements',
                                                    'FieldSet',
                                                     array('HtmlTag', 
                                                            array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'general')
                                                           )
                                                    )
                                )
                            );
```

I get this error :

```
    ArrayObject Object
    (
         [exception] => Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception Object
         (
             [message:protected] => Plugin by name 'FieldSet' was not found in the registry;   used paths:Zend_Form_Decorator_: Zend/Form/Decorator/
             [string:private] => 
             [code:protected] => 0
             [file:protected] => /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php
             [line:protected] => 406
             [trace:private] => Array
             ...................
```

How can I add the FieldSet plugin to the registry? I'm using the default Zend_Form Fieldset decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file Zend/Form/DisplayGroup.php, FieldSet was 'Fieldset' (lowercase 'S').
I changed it to Fieldset, and it works fine.

Comment: As the documentation clearly states [ZendForm](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.custom) is Fieldset with lowercase 'S'. I was experiencing the same error on my production site a Debian server. My developer environments (Win, OSX) didn't have any trouble as this OS are case-insensitive. Thanks, this was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Yet, there is something strange : when including several subforms and setting Decorators to contain Fieldset, if you mistake to FieldSet (with capital S) on some of them, there's no problem.

It seems that one lowercase solve the problem for all the others.

Also, you can load the FieldSet class from Zend (Zend_Form_Decorator_Fieldset) and have everything works with capital S.

(tested with Zend 1.11)